# Making roster program, having issues with creating the arrays, C#

Tags: c#, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

In c#

I am trying to make a simple program that will have a few functions such as adding and deleting members from a roster, search for a member, and display the current # of members.
This will later be built upon for more options, and saving the members to a file so it can actually be used over time. For now I just wanted the general layout setup before I even bothered with learning how to save the arrays to a file.

Now my question is: When the user chooses to create a new member for the roster it sends it to a function that will create a new employee with an array that will store Name and Division (just basic info for the test program). How would I create a multidimensional array without declaring how many rows it would need? I can not guess the amount of members due to eventual growth and reduction.

tl:dr Creating roster test program. How do I create a multidimensional array that would have a function add another row to it when a new member joins?

Comment: I would suggest create a `class Employee` with what ever properties you want and then Create List<Employee> which has built in feature of adding and removing elements. You can also convert this list `.ToArray()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are not resizable you would want to use `List<List<T>>` where `T` is the type of value you wish to store.

However you don't necessarily want to be storing the properties in an array, you really want to use a class instead.

```
public class Employee {
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Division {get;set;}
}
```

And then have a list of Employee

```
var roster = new List<Employee>();
```

To add a new Employee

```
roster.Add(new Employee { Name = "Mr Tiddles", Division = "Feline" });
```

Comment: Ok that does make much more sense. It is my first time touching c# so I was unfamiliar with how the gets/sets are in this, and it has been 3 or so years since I have touched code. Thank you much!